# Howto limit load_resource for users with multiple roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

In my application all users can read there own tasks. A second controller is only available for moderators and moderators can see all tasks.

```
# accessible for every user
# every user should see only own tasks, 
# but at the moment all moderators see all tasks
class TasksController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end

# only accessible for moderators, all tasks
class TasksModeratorController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :parent => false
end


# Ability
# Moderators can read all tasks
if user.moderator?
  can :read, Task
end
# All users can read there own tasks
can :read, Task, :user_id => user.id
```

How can i limit the tasks in TasksController to show only own tasks also to moderators but all tasks in TasksModeratorController? Or is there a more common way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Ability is a model since usually access rights are controller independent. But if not just make it explicit by passing the controller to the ability initialiser via current_ability.
I think this practise of passing more info to ability is encouraged. So my untested 2 cents

```
# in ApplicationController
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, self)
end

# in Ability
def initialize(user, controller)

# all same as before ...
# Moderators can read all tasks if using TasksModeratorController or any subclass
if user.moderator? && controller.is_a?(TasksModeratorController)
  can :read, Task
end

# All users can read there own tasks
can :read, Task, :user_id => user.id
```